# Resolved: How to create a Mongodb docker container without volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, automated-tests, docker-volume

I need to create a **snapshot** of a **MongoDB** in a specific state without volume, for auto-testing proposes.

To be clear, I need all of the data saved on the container memory and persist, not using a volume, then with a commit, I can take the snapshot.

After Jenkins will deploy this image from a repository, with initial data inside to run integration tests on it, and different executions of the test will run on the exact point of the database that we want. Without scripts or something like that.

I try changing the conf of **mongo** inside the container, docker compose.

Any idea or example will be grateful.

----------------------------solution------------------------------

if you need an image with initial data for sandboxing/testing purposes, you can do a docker file with all the conf and without volume declaration, that will force to save in the inner layers of memory in the container, then you can access and work normally until you have the state you like, next step is to make a snapshot.

Always you start the container you will find that concrete state in MongoDB for your test.

Answer (score 0):

Use Docker commit to save the state of a running container as an image:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: thx, but the data is in volume like I said, need the data on the container itself to commit make the trick

Comment: Yes, but you've to run it in memory using -tmpfs /data/db as a parameter. You can then do a docker commit on it to save. Note, I haven't tested this but it should work.